# Has anyone successfully used Azure AD to authenticate users for a Node.js web application?

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, passport.js, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate users for my node.js web application, so far with no luck.

I am wondering if anyone has actually ever achieved it since the documentation is quite poor.  There is typically example code, but not really any indication of what the required parameters are and what they should be.

I have tried passport-azure-ad (which I think is from Microsoft) and passport.azure-ad-oauth2 (which is from Auth0(?)).  For passport-azure-ad, I have tried the BearerStrategy and also the OIDCStrategy with no luck.

For BearerStrategy I get some cryptic message about my client and resource identifying the same application, but since there is no documentation telling me what those should be, I'm at a loss.

For the OIDCStrategy, I'm a bit closer in that I get redirected to Microsoft for authentication, but on return I get the error "Error: ID Token not present in response".  I'm guessing that my request isn't correct enough to give me a token back for whatever reason, but since there is no documentation...(you get the idea).

Anyway, if anyone has actually successfully achieved it and is able to share some pointers as to how it was achieved, that would be great.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a code example which is about integrating Azure AD into a NodeJS web application provided by Microsoft on GitHub, at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect.

And to make the sample run, you need to configure a few settings in the sample code about your Azure AD.

we can find the content as following shown in the `config.js` file in the root directory of the application:

```
exports.creds = {
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return',
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration', // For using Microsoft you should never need to change this.
    clientID: '<your app id>',
    clientSecret: '<your secret>', // if you are doing code or id_token code
    skipUserProfile: true, // for AzureAD should be set to true.
    responseType: 'id_token code', // for login only flows use id_token. For accessing resources use `id_token code`
    responseMode: 'query', // For login only flows we should have token passed back to us in a POST
    //scope: ['email', 'profile'] // additional scopes you may wish to pass
 };
```

now you need to login the Azure manage portal, header to your Azure AD application page. Click the **CONFIGURE** tab to configure your AD.

- Input the `returnURL` in `config.js` into the `REPLY URL` form under the single sign-on section:
  [image]
- fill the Azure AD endpoint of your AD application into the `identityMetadata` property in `config.js`. As the comment in the code says, if your Azure AD is in the Microsoft domain like: [image]
  Then you don't have to change the setting. Otherwise, you need to replace the `common` in the endpoint in `config.js` to your AD ID, you can click the **VIEW ENDPOINT** at the bottom nav to find the ID:[image]
- configure the `clientID` and `clientSecret` in `config.js`. You all can find them in the **CONFIGRE** page of your AD application:
  [image]
  About the key, you can select the dropdown to select a duration of a key to create a new one, click the save button at the bottom nav, you can see the key data at first time you create it.

After finishing these steps, you can try the sample project.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did try that, but it didn't work.  The original microsoft code I had identityMetadata as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration but since changing that to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration as in your example, I've had a little more luck...

Comment: Do you still occur the issue after changing the endpoint to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration` ?

Comment: The new (old?) endpoint seems to work.  I'm a bit uncomfortable about it though since the example has what would appear to be a newer endpoint and why would they use an endpoint in the example that doesn't work?  Many thanks for your responses...

Comment: If you change the response mode from `query` to `form_post` in `config.js` and check the response body, there is an `error_description: 'Application \'application_id\' is not supported for this API version'` when using v2.0 endpoint. However I also found this: https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/pull/55/files, I am wondering if it has to do with how oauth2 protocol works.

Comment: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` with `form_post`? it works fine on my side. You can check your settings

Answer (score 1):

For me this (No Code solution) worked in the [new Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com):

- host my Node.js Server
- add an AD to the subscription
- Register new application within the AD
- Add "https://YourNodeJS.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback" as Reply URL
- In AppServices, pick your Node.js Server
- In Settings go to Authentication/Authorization
- Activate AAD
- Use Advanced Mode of AAD
- Enter the ClientID (GUID) of the application registered above in AD
- As issuerURL enter this link: https://sts.windows.net/YourADGuid/ (you can see the GUID within "Endpoints" if you look back at your application registered in AD above)