# Register Application in Azure AD - node.js passport-azure-ad example

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js, azure-active-directory

I am trying to setup a authentification for POST requests on my Node.js server hosted @ Azure.

I am using [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) example:

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
    callbackURL: config.creds.returnURL,
    realm: config.creds.realm,
    clientID: config.creds.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.creds.clientSecret,
    oidcIssuer: config.creds.issuer,
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantGuidOrTheWordCOMMON/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    skipUserProfile: config.creds.skipUserProfile,
    responseType: config.creds.responseType,
    responseMode: config.creds.responseMode,
    (tenant: "Guid from AzureAD-Endpoints-Button"),
    (validateIssuer: false/true)
      }, (...)
```

Although my code redirects me to a "https://login.microsoftonline.com" page (which is nice), after entering my email-address it immediately redirects me somewhere else.

There I get an error in the browserUrl: "the client does not exist"...
and it says I should create an application @ "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com".

WHY? I have a AppService "MyService", an Azure AD within the same subscription and within the Azure AD an "App registration" for "MyApp".

- What is now this cruel apps.dev.microsoft site? Why is there not my registered "MyApp" shown and Vice versa?
- What do I have to enter within "oidcIssuer"? the MyApp.ApplicationId? The (apps.dev.microsoft.com)-Application.ApplicationId? The AzureAD-ClientId? The AzureAD-IssuerUrl?
- The same question for the clientSecret
- Whats the difference between using identityMetadata with an ID instead of "common" + validateIssuer:true against using identityMetadata with "common", validateIssuer:false + tenant:"myTenant(Guid?)"
- When I Use "ExpressSettings" within Authentication/Authorization-->AzureAD why can I not find the Application I defined in Azure AD?
- Do I have to activate the Graph API (I dont know anything about it yet)
- Are there good alternatives protecting my express.post endpoint with authentification in Azure AD? (ADAL seems to be for resources)

I dont get all this settings, properties and portals of Microsoft I am just overhelmed by all this... (not to mention there is also an "OLD" portal)

The next days I will try [this Azure Step-By-Step Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/) maybe It will help me somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my answer to ["Has anyone successfully used Azure AD to authenticate users for a Node.js web application?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996807/has-anyone-successfully-used-azure-ad-to-authenticate-users-for-a-node-js-web-ap/39786474#39786474)

I setup my authentification like this instead (without code) in the [new Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com):

- host my Node.js Server
- add an AD to the subscription
- Register new application within the AD
- Add "https://YourNodeJS.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback" as Reply URL
- In AppServices, pick your Node.js Server
- In Settings go to Authentication/Authorization
- Activate AAD
- Use Advanced Mode of AAD
- Enter the ClientID (GUID) of the application registered above in AD
- As issuerURL enter this link: https://sts.windows.net/YourADGuid/ (you can see the GUID within "Endpoints" if you look back at your application registered in AD above)

Answer (score 0):

For this example you are using, you don't need to modify the params in `OIDCStrategy` object. Instead, you need to config your AAD settings in `client_config_*.js.` files. Just like the document describes at https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/tree/master/examples/login-oidc.

And BTW, we manage our AAD applications on the [Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).